# Is it possible to have nested queries in Postgres pg module

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg

Here is my code that tries to update a record in the db. 
But if the record is not there then I want to insert it.
Is it OK to call client.query again? Or what's the best way to do it?

```
const {Pool} = require('pg');
const pool   = new Pool(POSTGRES_CONFIG);

pool.connect((err, client, release) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.error('Error acquiring client', err.stack)
    }

    ………

    client.query(query, queryValues, (err, result) => {
        release();

        if(result.rowCount<=0){
            //**** CAN I CALL IT AGAIN WITH OTHER PARAMETERS TO INSERT? ****
            client.query(....... => {
                release();

                if (err) {
                    if(err.code === POSTGRES_ERRORS.UNIQUE_VIOLATION){
                        return console.error('KEY ALREADY EXISTS');
                    } else {
                        return console.error('query error', err);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is perfectly OK as long as you call `release` after you're done with the client. From the docs:

> You must call the releaseCallback or client.release (which points to
>   the releaseCallback) when you are finished with a client.

So, you could do this:

```
client.query(query, queryValues, (err, result) => {
        // don't release just yet 

        if(result.rowCount<=0){
            //**** CAN I CALL IT AGAIN WITH OTHER PARAMETERS TO INSERT? ****
            client.query(....... => {
                release(); // now you're done with the client so you can release it

                if (err) {
                    if(err.code === POSTGRES_ERRORS.UNIQUE_VIOLATION){
                        return console.error('KEY ALREADY EXISTS');
                    } else {
                        return console.error('query error', err);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Works perfect.. Thank you Daniel